# Change Origin for UIViewAnimationCurve

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation-curve

I'm new to Xcode and I can't find anything on this. I want to use UIViewAnimationCurve to move a UIImage from the lower left corner of the view to the upper left. I know the iPhone origin is upper left. How do I change this to the lower left so the animation can end in the upper right? This is what I have so far:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                      delay:2
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{[MyImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0,200, 82, 78)]; }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [MyImage setFrame:CGRectMake(200,0, 82, 78)];
                 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to (a) establish the view's origin in the lower left corner and then (b) animate the transition to the upper left corner.

```
//  step a
[MyImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 82, 78)];

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                      delay:2
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
                   //  step b
                   [MyImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 82, 78)];
                  }
                 completion:nil];
```

The view's frame will be set during the animation, no need for that work to be done in the completion block as well.

NB: your phrase "I want to use UIViewAnimationCurve..." is very misleading.  A more commonplace way to phrase your request would have been "I want to use UIView animations...".  To be very clear, the `UIViewAnimationCurve` enum refers to the rate at which the animation is animated, start-to-finish; `UIViewAnimationCurveLinear` means that the animation will proceed start-to-finish in a smooth, linear rate.